# How to display a ProgressDialog while executing a background task?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to display a process dialog for a particular time in front of an activity while other tasks performed in background . i don't want to use asynkTask as am updating the ui inside that method. 
please help

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at your **AsycTasks** methods `onPreExecute(...)` and `onPostExecute(...)`.
Use the first to show the ProgressDialog, and the second to dismiss it when the task is finished.

`OnPreExecute()` will be called before your background-process starts. `OnPostExecute()` will be called when your task has finished.

```
// the below code is inside your asynctask class

private ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){ 
   super.onPreExecute();

   pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
   pd.setMessage("Processing...");
   pd.show();    
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // do stuff
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   pd.dismiss();
}
```